# wget works fine for some .jpgs but downloads an .html file instead for others

Tags: wget

I want to download web images from the command line.
This works fine sometimes, other times it doesn't and I can't figure out why.
Here's an example (Wikimedia Commons picture of the day):

```
wget https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Main_Page#/media/File:01_Calanche_Piana.jpg
```

This somehow gets me an .html

```
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 185986 (182K) [text/html]
Saving to: 'Main_Page'
```

The following however (it's the same picture but with explicitly selected resolution) gets me a .jpg (which is what I want)

```
wget https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/01/01_Calanche_Piana.jpg/640px-01_Calanche_Piana.jpg
...
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 118796 (116K) [image/jpeg]
Saving to: '640px-01_Calanche_Piana.jpg'
```

I tried adding `-O test.jpg` to the first example, this will still be an .html file though.
Does anyone know why the command works in one case but not in the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why the command works in one case but not in the other?

This one

```
https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Main_Page#/media/File:01_Calanche_Piana.jpg
```

despite what last letter might suggest is link to HTML page, note that there is `#` which is used to denote [URI fragment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_fragment), whilst this one

```
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/01/01_Calanche_Piana.jpg/640px-01_Calanche_Piana.jpg
```

is URL to actual image. If you wondering what type of file is under given URL, but do not want to download that file you might do

```
wget -S --spider https://www.example.com
```

It will show you response headers, there might be many of them, but for determining type of resource [`Content-Type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) should suffice.